# creating captcha image in php when uploaded to server

Tags: php

using the code below to ceate image used in captch, it works fine in localhost but when i upload to server no image is rendered.

```
<?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $text = $_SESSION['secure']; 
    $font_size = 30;

    $image_width = 120;
    $image_height = 40;

    $image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
    imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

    for ($x=1; $x<=299; $x++) { 
        $x1 = rand(1, 999);
        $y1 = rand(1, 999);
        $x2 = rand(1, 100);
        $y2 = rand(1, 100);
        imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $text_color);
    }


    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 33, $text_color, 'fonts/font.TTf', $text);
    imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: error message? no all servers support all functions

Comment: you have error checking and display on?

Comment: I think the problem here is that there is not permission to access `truetype` file in your server. Try enabling `ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your script to get some more information.

Comment: i put the above code and i get no errors

Comment: make sure you have uploaded 'core/init.php' too and session_start();

Comment: 'fonts/font.TTf' is uploaded too?

Comment: Do you have php_gd2 extension enabled ?

Comment: the font is uploaded. How do i check if php_gd2 extension is enabled